# Extract multiline text between two strings using python

Tags: python, text, split

I have a text file which looks like the below dummy file

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
some random characters and then start of my data
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
end of my data
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
in the 1960s with the release of Letraset 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
some random characters and then start of my data
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
end of my data
sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
and more recently with desktop publishing
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
some random characters and then start of my data
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
some characters in between
end of my data
software like Aldus PageMaker including
versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

I want to extract data between "start of my data" till "end of my data" and save it on a list variable. This data comes multiple times on the text file. I tried the below code for it

```
import re
import sys
s=[]
with open('mytextfile.txt','r') as file:
    mystring = file.read()
    myre = re.compile(r"start of my data(.*?)end of my data", re.DOTALL)
    parts = myre.findall(mystring)
    s.append(parts)
```

This code saves all the found strings at once on the first index of the list. but i need each separate data on a new index. How i can achieve this?

Comment: Split the data by newline?

Comment: Yes, newline starting from start of data to end of data

Answer (score 0):

With `s.append(parts)` you append the whole list `parts` as a single element to the array `s`, that's why `s` ends up having only one element (which is a list of 3 elements). Instead you need `s.extend(parts)` if you want to append the 3 elements of `parts` individually to `s`.

Comment: After reading the comments, it looks you may want to split the individual parts further by newlines, in that case the answer by @Thomas Weller seems to do the trick (additionally you may want to do `part.strip().split("\n")` if you want to avoid having empty elements at the beginning and end of each part).

Answer (score 0):

Split the data lines of your capture group by `\n`:

```py
import re
s=[]
mystring = """
paste your string here
"""
myre = re.compile(r"start of my data(.*?)end of my data", re.DOTALL)
parts = myre.findall(mystring)
for part in parts:
    s.extend(part.split("\n"))
print(len(s))
```

Result for the example data provided is 24.